# Error building `Cairo`:Warning: skipping repodata/repomd.xml, not in cache -- call WinRPM.update() to download

Tags: julia

I want to install Luxor in Julia-1.1.1. on Windows but it fails during compiling with the message "Cairo not properly installed", and also that I should build Cairo using `Pkg.build`. When I do this I get the following error:

```
Pkg.build("Cairo")
Building LibCURL ─→ `C:\Users\Th\.julia\packages\LibCURL\teHPG\deps\build.log`
  Building WinRPM ──→ `C:\Users\Th\.julia\packages\WinRPM\Y9QdZ\deps\build.log`
  Building Homebrew → `C:\Users\Th\.julia\packages\Homebrew\s09IX\deps\build.log`
  Building Cairo ───→ `C:\Users\Th\.julia\packages\Cairo\p68X8\deps\build.log`

┌ Error: Error building `Cairo`: 
│ ┌ Warning: skipping repodata/repomd.xml, not in cache -- call WinRPM.update() to download
│ └ @ WinRPM C:\Users\Th\.julia\packages\WinRPM\Y9QdZ\src\WinRPM.jl:148
│ ┌ Warning: skipping repodata/repomd.xml, not in cache -- call WinRPM.update() to download
│ └ @ WinRPM C:\Users\Th\.julia\packages\WinRPM\Y9QdZ\src\WinRPM.jl:148
│ [ Info: Updating WinRPM package list
│ [ Info: Downloading https://cache.julialang.org/http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml
…
```

`versioninfo()` shows:

```
Julia Version 1.1.1
Commit 55e36cc308 (2019-05-16 04:10 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210M CPU @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)
```

BACKGROUND: 
On my search for appropriate graphics packages in Julia I have tried to install e.g. Vega, VegaLite, etc. - and now Luxor - but most of them failed with the same error message. What works so far is Gadfly with Compose.

Right now, I am using Jupyter Lab but I got the same error in REPL, in Atom, and also with earlier versions of Julia, such as 0.7, and above.

Could someone help me on the Cairo Problem? BTW, I am a newbie in programming, so please, be patient with me :)

Comment: You can get help on Cairo.jl errors on [github](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Cairo.jl/issues) where there are many other reports of problems with Windows installs. Perhaps there are solutions there too - search for WinRPM which is often the problem.

Comment: Pavel, thanks a lot. I'll search there for possible answers...